# Modeling the area-preserving deformation of $r=a\left(1+\cos\left(n\theta\right)\right)$ into a circle of equal area centered at origin (graph incl.)

Tags: solution-verification, deformation-theory

I want to know if the equation I give here to model the transformation works as expected

For this post let $n$ be a positive integer greater than one

Define:

$$W=\frac{a}{2}\left(1-T\right)\cos\left(\left(n+1\right)b\right)+\frac{a}{2}\left(1-T\right)\cos\left(\left(n-1\right)b\right)+a\left(1-T\right)\cos b+T\sqrt{\frac{A_{1}}{\pi}}\cos b$$

$$Z=\frac{a}{2}\left(1-T\right)\left(n+1\right)\cos\left(\left(n+1\right)b\right)+\frac{a}{2}\left(1-T\right)\left(1-n\right)\cos\left(\left(1-n\right)b\right)+a\left(1-T\right)\cos b+T\sqrt{\frac{A_{1}}{\pi}}\cos b$$

$$B_{1}=A_{1}$$

$$B_{2}=A_{2}$$

$$q=0$$

$$A_{3}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\sqrt{\frac{B_{1}}{B_{2}}+q}W\right)\left(\sqrt{\frac{B_{1}}{B_{2}}+q}Z\right)db$$

$$X_{1}=\frac{a}{2}\cos\left(\left(n+1\right)u\right)+\frac{a}{2}\cos\left(\left(n-1\right)u\right)+a\cos u$$

$$Y_{1}=\frac{a}{2}\left(n+1\right)\cos\left(\left(n+1\right)u\right)+\frac{a}{2}\left(1-n\right)\cos\left(\left(1-n\right)u\right)+a\cos u$$

$$A_{1}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}X_{1}Y_{1}du$$

$$h\left(t\right)=f\left(t\right)+T\left(g\left(t\right)-f\left(t\right)\right)$$

$$X_{2}=\frac{a}{2}\left(1-T\right)\cos\left(\left(n+1\right)w\right)+\frac{a}{2}\left(1-T\right)\cos\left(\left(n-1\right)w\right)+a\left(1-T\right)\cos w+T\sqrt{\frac{A_{1}}{\pi}}\cos w$$

$$Y_{2}=\frac{a}{2}\left(1-T\right)\left(n+1\right)\cos\left(\left(n+1\right)w\right)+\frac{a}{2}\left(1-T\right)\left(1-n\right)\cos\left(\left(1-n\right)w\right)+a\left(1-T\right)\cos w+T\sqrt{\frac{A_{1}}{\pi}}\cos w$$

$$A_{2}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}X_{2}Y_{2}dw$$

Model the starting shape by
$$f\left(t\right)=\left(\frac{a}{2}\cos\left(\left(n+1\right)t\right)+\frac{a}{2}\cos\left(\left(n-1\right)t\right)+a\cos t,\frac{a}{2}\sin\left(\left(n+1\right)t\right)+\frac{a}{2}\sin\left(\left(1-n\right)t\right)+a\sin t\right)$$

Model the resultant circle by
$$g\left(t\right)=\sqrt{\frac{A_{1}}{\pi}}\left(\cos t,\sin t\right)$$

Then the continuous deformation of the starting shape into a circle centered at the origin can be modeled by the equation

$$H\left(t\right)=\sqrt{\frac{A_{1}}{A_{2}}}h\left(t\right)$$

where the $T$ in $h\left(t\right)=f\left(t\right)+T\left(g\left(t\right)-f\left(t\right)\right)$ goes from zero to 1.

For a given time slice at $T=T_0$ one obtains an intermediate curve whose enclosed area is the same as the enclosed area of the starting curve

[This link to my desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xeomvrdfm3) models the transformation using the equations above.

To verify that enclosed area is preserved, see that the $A_3$ remains constant as $T$ varies only if $q=0$